# login with xcode

Tags: objective-c

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"uname=%@&upassword=%@",textname.text, textpass.text];
NSString *hostStr = @"http://IP:port/abc/login.jsp?";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];    
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:
NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

But problem is not getting response from the server and as i programmed.all kind of login details returning some value but on this page getting nothing.. ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yourpagenaem/check-user.jsp?          uname=%@&upassword=%@",textname.text,textpass.text];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:7.0];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
int statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
```

Check this out...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` instead of just `dataWithContentsOfURL:`.  Check the error parameter to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code,it will surely Help you**

```
 NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uname=%@&upassword=%@",textname.text, textpass.text];    
 NSData *postData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];    
 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

 // preaparing URL request to send data.

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
 NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://IP:port/abc/login.jsp?"];
 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [request setHTTPBody:postData];
 [request setTimeoutInterval:7.0];

 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSError *error;

 NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
 NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSLog(@"Login response:%@",str);
```